# Trying to insert an SQL query into a commandline window with Java

Tags: java, sql, command-prompt

first post - and complete newcomer to language but you have to start somewhere. at the moment my Problem is as follows

1: open the command line window & go to specific directory

2: run an 3rd party .exe (LogParser.exe) from there with an SQL query as its argument

I know about Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe"); but this just brings up the command window.

but how do I complete the second step i.e. insert the query ? 
Is it possible to process the SQL query as a string and pass it to the command window ?

e.g. the output from to the command window would look something like this

Logparser.exe "select top 5 * from application"

Maybe this is very basic but and if it is apologies but basic is where I'm at right now too

Comment: Are you surely do not want to connect to db using JDBC?

Comment: No - (not yet anyway). Reason I am doing it this way is just to see if i can get the information from LogParser while running in the background. Log Parser will output the info to the cmd screen when you run it. If I can get this query to work then I can manipulate others to write to a file etc and interrogate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\path\to\LogParser.exe", "select top 5 * from application");
Process p = pb.start();
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
p.waitFor();
char c;
while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
  System.out.print(c);
}
is.close();
```

If you absolutely have to use a Command prompt then you can use `p.getOutputStream()` to send strings to the other process's input buffer (STDIN).

(Tested the above code on Unix with "ls", "-l" written in Groovy so YMMV.)

Comment: Hi - thanks for that. It kinda works. Problem is that with Log Parser - when you go to run it automatically like your example it opens the full windows application and wont run the subsequent query. only workaround I can think of is to try and open the windows console in the correct location first and then run another method to insert the the following string "LogParser.exe "select top 5 * from application"

Comment: Open `cmd.exe` as you see above, but pass the commands as strings to the Process.getOutputStream() as if they were what the end user typed in.

Comment: Hi - I found a way. I created a batch file in windows put the query into the batch file and ran the exe off it through Java                             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /c start C:\\Temp\\test.bat");